# Set default value for select html element in Jinja template while using range

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have 3 fields for which I need to set the default value if it is available. 3 fields are day, month and year. It works fine if all the options are listed but doesn't work if I'm using range. To populate day and year fields, I'm using Jinja's range function:

```
{% for n in range(1,31) %}  
 <option value="{{n}}" {% if selectedDay==n%} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{n}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

What should be correct approach while using range?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Is there an error?

Comment: For e.g If the value of selectedDay is 5 then in the drop down options 5 should already be selected. And that doesn't seems to be happening.

Comment: I just tested your code and it worked fine. Are you sure that selectedDay is the right value?

Comment: Perhaps the value of selectedDay is not an integer?

Comment: @dizzyf that was the issue indeed